# Getting syntax error while checking the file size

Tags: python

While checking the file size in `MB` i am getting the syntax error using Python.

I am getting the syntax error within the `if....statement`.

```
def createfile(request):
      param = request.POST.get('param')
        file_info = os.stat(param)
        result = convert_bytes(file_info.st_size)
        if result > 1 'MB' :
             return render(request, 'plant/status.html',
                          {'message': "File size should be within 1 mb."})


def convert_bytes(num):
    """ This function is used for measure file size """

    for xe in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']:
        if num < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (num, x)
                num /= 1024.0
```

Comment: Not sure you did it or not but the function " convert_bytes " should come before the function " createfile " ?

Comment: Try: `if result > '1 MB' :` - although that condition doesnt make much sense

Comment: @MauriceMeyer has a good point! Try that!

Comment: Always add your traceback... Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Your indentation in `createfile` is also wrong, but that may just be a typo in the question.

Answer (score 2):

`if result > 1 'MB' :`
is where your problem is. You're comparing `result` to an integer 1 and you have  a string directly after. Perhaps you meant `'1 MB'`. This will still not help you because comparing strings by the '>' operator doesn't really work. Compare it to just an integer whether that's 1 or 1000 (because of kilobytes). Try something like that.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yeah :) however `convert_bytes()` gives it is how he should compare it.